# Использование псевдоэлемента

Tags: css3

Всем привет.

Есть картинка для  `background`, ее нужно сделать на пару тонов темнее.

Обнаружила ***упущение***, сверстав уже **2** секции. Вернулась и исправила это дело, применив `::before`.

Но теперь выходит, что все `h && p` тоже темнее, чем должны.

Может, я изначально подошла к задаче неверно, потому что, сверив свой код с ***правильным  вариантом (задачей - как хотите)***, обнаружила, цвета шрифтов у нас одинаковые, и  `::before` тоже применили. Но вот только чтобы соответствовать макету, мне теперь нужно играться с цветами...

Что-то тут не ладно.

Но вот что ?

```
header{
    background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
header::before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно,что у вас там не так по задаче, но если вы хотите чтобы затемнение применялось только к одному элементу, задайте ему отдельный класс и примените before к этому классу

Comment: Вы, Кристина, подошли не верно, не к задаче,  а к оформлению вопроса...  Какой то абстрактный вопрос, как помочь когда не понятно, что должно быть, что получилось и в чем именно проблема...

Comment: надо, поиграть с `z-index-ОМ`

Answer (score 2):

Подскажу способ затенения картинки без использования псевдоэлементов, который я нашёл.

Я не знаю, есть ли проще или как ещё можно использовать данную приблуду, но я использовал её так и у меня всё было нормально.

Использовать я буду: **background-image: linear-gradient();**

Прикладываю ссылку на поддержку браузерами: [ссылка](https://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient)

```css
body{
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url("https://wallpapershome.com/images/wallpapers/wave-3840x2160-5k-4k-wallpaper-8k-ocean-palms-sun-5490.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test subject</h1>
```

Да, есть и с псевдоэлементами, но в нём необходимо менять Z-INDEX объектов, что добавит несколько строк кода. Опять же, возможно есть проще способ, но я привёл тот что знаю лично.